# how to get the email address from inserted data as the recipient in sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I would like to use the email address that is inserted in a column as the `@recipient` in `sp_send_dbmail`. This code is a trigger that I've been trying to achieve this with and is for test purposes only:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON dbo.table1
   FOR INSERT AS
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @recipients VARCHAR(255)
   SET @email = @recipients
   SET @recipients = @recipients
  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
       @profile_name='dbmail',
       @recipients = @recipients,
       @subject ='Test message',
       @body_format= 'html',
       @body= @body`
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `INSERTED` pseudo table when working in triggers? Also, keep in mind that triggers fire once per insert. If multiple rows are inserted in one `INSERT` statement, the trigger will fire once for the set of rows, and your trigger should expect that pseudo table to have multiple rows in it.

Comment: i managed to send the inserted data to myself , just wanted to change @recipients to inserted value

Comment: @AMtwo i used the code that I posted as answer to send the inserted data to myself

Comment: in this situation a user fills out a webform and the data is uploaded, i dont think it will ever be possible for multiple rows to be inserted

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger ON dbo.table1
FOR INSERT AS

DECLARE @fname VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @lname VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @body VARCHAR(255)


SELECT @fname=(fname) FROM INSERTED
SELECT @lname=(lname) FROM INSERTED
SELECT @email=(email) FROM INSERTED

SET @body = @fname + @lname + @email

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @profile_name='default',
     @recipients = '',
     @subject='Test message',
     @body= @body
```

Comment: But this logic suffers from a very common flaw. Your trigger assumes a single row is inserted. A trigger executes at the statement level and must correctly handle any number of row affected by the associated statement - from zero (yes) to many.  And this `@recipients = ''` seems to be problem, no?

Comment: @SMor it is my intention that the data shall be uploaded from a web form to db , the user fills in the form fields and the all are inserted in one row, so i think in this manner the trigger will only ever handle one row at a time ?? the @recipients'??????' is the value i want to fill with the email value from inserted data, im thinking now that its not possible because of the mail procedure cant read external data from outside the stored procedure if i understand it correctly,